# Can't rearrange open chat tabs anymore?

Tags: facebook

I used to be able to rearrange open chat tabs in Facebook, clicking and dragging them left or right. This stopped working recently (a month or two ago).

I've tried it with regular Chrome, Chrome in incognito mode (no extensions) and IE11, and it works on none of them.

Is this something Facebook did on purpose or is it a bug?

Answer (score 1):

I tried from 2 different account and 4 different web browsers. Seems like Facebook has discontinued it.

**Edit**- Reference to discontinuation is based on self experience, no authoritative proof.

Comment: Which browsers? Reference to discontinuation?

Comment: Google Chrome latest build, Firefox, Internet Explorer, Safari.

Edit: Reference to discontinuation is based on self experience, no authoritative proof. Let me edit my answer and add that.